# how do a2b_hex() python but in godot

Tags: python, hex, godot

i am wondering how do i use the python a2b_hex() but in Godot . For example the data is ("000100007AD59C7918B839F02C8483CFEA1ECBDA") and when calling the function a2b_hex() and prints out (b'\x00\x01\x00\x00z\xd5\x9cy\x18\xb89\xf0,\x84\x83\xcf\xea\x1e\xcb\xda') but i want this to also work in Godot .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a matching function in Godot.

Anyway, we are going to build an `PoolByteArray` from the hex input (so we are not doing a bunch of `String` concatenations). We could get an `String` from it, but… Well, we will get to that.

The plan would be to take two by two of characters of the input string, interpret them as hexadecimal, and write them to the result in the appropriate position.

We are going to need to have two lengths:

- The length of the the input `String`, which I'll call `hex_length`.
- The length of the result `PoolByteArray`, which I'll call `byte_length`.

We can get `hex_length` like this:

```
func hex_to_byte_array(hex:String) -> PoolByteArray:
    var hex_length := hex.length()
```

So we will compute `byte_length` from it by dividing by two:

```
func hex_to_byte_array(hex:String) -> PoolByteArray:
    var hex_length := hex.length()
    var byte_length := hex_length / 2
```

Oh, a warning! This is an integer division and we could be losing precision… Well, if `hex_length` is not even, we are in trouble. I don't know how you want to handle that case, I'll just push an error and suppress the warning:

```
func hex_to_byte_array(hex:String) -> PoolByteArray:
    var hex_length := hex.length()
    if hex_length % 2 == 1:
        push_error("Not even length hex input")
        return PoolByteArray()

    # warning-ignore:integer_division
    var byte_length := hex_length / 2
```

**Note**: You can also check `is_valid_hex_number`.

And we can go ahead and allocate the result:

```
func hex_to_byte_array(hex:String) -> PoolByteArray:
    var hex_length := hex.length()
    if hex_length % 2 == 1:
        push_error("Not even length hex input")
        return PoolByteArray()

    # warning-ignore:integer_division
    var byte_length := hex_length / 2
    var result := PoolByteArray()
    result.resize(byte_length)
```

Similarly to the two lengths, we will have two position:

- The position on the input `String`, which I'll call `hex_index`.
- The position on the result `PoolByteArray`, which I'll call `byte_index`.

Now, I have a choice about what do I want to iterate over… If I iterate over the input `String` I need skip each other number (I only want the even numbers). So it is easier for me to iterate over the result `PoolByteArray`.

Thus, I will iterate with `byte_index` and compute `hex_index` from it like this: `hex_index = byte_index * 2`.

Well, actually like this: `hex_index = ìnt(byte_index) * 2`. Because sadly the variable on the loop does not have an static type, and I like static types.

That looks like this:

```
func hex_to_byte_array(hex:String) -> PoolByteArray:
    var hex_length := hex.length()
    if hex_length % 2 == 1:
        push_error("Not even length hex input")
        return PoolByteArray()

    # warning-ignore:integer_division
    var byte_length := hex_length / 2
    var result := PoolByteArray()
    result.resize(byte_length)
    for byte_index in byte_length:
        var hex_index := int(byte_index) * 2
```

Now we get the two hex characters with `substr`:

```
func hex_to_byte_array(hex:String) -> PoolByteArray:
    var hex_length := hex.length()
    if hex_length % 2 == 1:
        push_error("Not even length hex input")
        return PoolByteArray()

    # warning-ignore:integer_division
    var byte_length := hex_length / 2
    var result := PoolByteArray()
    result.resize(byte_length)
    for byte_index in byte_length:
        var hex_index := int(byte_index) * 2
        var hex_couple := hex.substr(hex_index, 2)
```

And, a bit inconvenient, the function to convert hex to integer requires a `"0x"` prefix, so let us do that:

```
func hex_to_byte_array(hex:String) -> PoolByteArray:
    var hex_length := hex.length()
    if hex_length % 2 == 1:
        push_error("Not even length hex input")
        return PoolByteArray()

    # warning-ignore:integer_division
    var byte_length := hex_length / 2
    var result := PoolByteArray()
    result.resize(byte_length)
    for byte_index in byte_length:
        var hex_index := int(byte_index) * 2
        var hex_couple := hex.substr(hex_index, 2)
        var hex_value := ("0x" + hex_couple).hex_to_int()
```

And that is what we need to write in the result:

```
func hex_to_byte_array(hex:String) -> PoolByteArray:
    var hex_length := hex.length()
    if hex_length % 2 == 1:
        push_error("Not even length hex input")
        return PoolByteArray()

    # warning-ignore:integer_division
    var byte_length := hex_length / 2
    var result := PoolByteArray()
    result.resize(byte_length)
    for byte_index in byte_length:
        var hex_index := int(byte_index) * 2
        var hex_couple := hex.substr(hex_index, 2)
        result[byte_index] = ("0x" + hex_couple).hex_to_int()
```

Oh, right, and return:

```
func hex_to_byte_array(hex:String) -> PoolByteArray:
    var hex_length := hex.length()
    if hex_length % 2 == 1:
        push_error("Not even length hex input")
        return PoolByteArray()

    # warning-ignore:integer_division
    var byte_length := hex_length / 2
    var result := PoolByteArray()
    result.resize(byte_length)
    for byte_index in byte_length:
        var hex_index := int(byte_index) * 2
        var hex_couple := hex.substr(hex_index, 2)
        result[byte_index] = ("0x" + hex_couple).hex_to_int()
    
    return result
```

---

And if want an `String`, you could do this:

```
func hex_to_string(hex:String) -> String:
    return hex_to_byte_array(hex).get_string_from_ascii()
```

Except that is not good. For, you see, the example input you have provided starts with `00`, so a null terminated `String` ends there. So I hope you are OK working with the `PoolByteArray` instead.

---

By the way, for testing I made a method that iterates over the `PoolByteArray` and build an escaped `String`:

```
func hex_test(hex:String) -> String:
    var result := ""
    for code in hex_to_byte_array(hex):
        var tmp := PoolByteArray([code])
        if code >= 32 and code <= 126:
            var s := tmp.get_string_from_ascii()
            result += s
        else:
            result += "\\x" + tmp.hex_encode()

    return result
```

So this:

```
print (hex_test("000100007AD59C7918B839F02C8483CFEA1ECBDA"))
```

Outputs this:

> \x00\x01\x00\x00z\xd5\x9cy\x18\xb89\xf0,\x84\x83\xcf\xea\x1e\xcb\xda

Which matches the example in the question.

Comment: one more question were can i learned about hex and bytes what book do you recommend or article to learn this kind of stuff?

Comment: @alexhernandez I don't have something in particular to point you to. However, there is plenty of material a search away. For example I found this video: [How To Convert Hexadecimal to Binary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_YC6DSPpQE) searching "hex bytes base conversion" in YouTube.

Comment: this works in the latest godot 4 using PackedByteArray instead. thank you, I am not sure why a hex_encode method exists but not a decode_hex...

Comment: @scape I had wrote a reply saying nobody has done it… but turns out there was a pull request yesterday, which just got merged. You can expect `String.hex_decode` in the next release of Godot.